# How to fix Package source mapping is off in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package

I see the message **Package source mapping is off** in Visual Studio 2022 17.8.0 when I click on any package in the NuGet package manager.

[image]

When I click on the Configure link, it opens up the below window.

I also have a question what does this error mean? Why am I seeing this error? Do I need to fix it or can I ignore it?

[image]

Comment: It's not an error. It's an informational message. You can learn more about package source mapping, to decide if you want to use it or not, from the docs page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by @Tianyu, I am posting this as an answer.

I was able to solve the issue by following the below documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping#enable-by-using-visual-studio-options-dialog

Once you click on Configure link, it will open the window, you can configure the package like the below.

[image]